# Record Audio Using AudioRecord in android

Tags: android, audio, android-2.2-froyo, android-audiorecord

From the below code  I can create test.pcm file but I couldn't play it in mobile or pc.

I have also tired with test.mp3, test.wav and test.raw. I got toast that player doesn't support this type of file.

does any one has idea that how can i play file which is i have recorded using AudioRecord?

Using below code I get array of short from mic and write it into SdCard.

Here is the Code:

```
package com.anroid.AudioProcess;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;


public class AudioProcess extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Record 20 seconds of audio.
        Recorder recorderInstance = new Recorder();
        Thread th = new Thread(recorderInstance);
        recorderInstance.setFileName(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test.pcm"));
        th.start();
        recorderInstance.setRecording(true);
        synchronized (this) {
        try {
            this.wait(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
        recorderInstance.setRecording(false);
        try {
            th.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}





 class Recorder implements Runnable {
    private int frequency;
    private int channelConfiguration;
    private volatile boolean isPaused;
    private File fileName;
    private volatile boolean isRecording;
    private final Object mutex = new Object();

    // Changing the sample resolution changes sample type. byte vs. short.
    private static final int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Recorder() {
        super();
        this.setFrequency(11025);
        this.setChannelConfiguration(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO);
        this.setPaused(false);
    }

    public void run() {
        // Wait until we're recording...
        synchronized (mutex) {
            while (!this.isRecording) {
                try {
                    mutex.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Wait() interrupted!", e);
                }
            }
        }

        // Open output stream...
        if (this.fileName == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("fileName is null");
        }
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedStreamInstance = null;
        if (fileName.exists()) {
            fileName.delete();
        }
        try {
            fileName.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot create file: " + fileName.toString());
        }
        try {
            bufferedStreamInstance = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(this.fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot Open File", e);
        }
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStreamInstance = 
            new DataOutputStream(bufferedStreamInstance);

        // We're important...
        android.os.Process
                .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

        // Allocate Recorder and Start Recording...
        int bufferRead = 0;
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(this.getFrequency(),
                this.getChannelConfiguration(), this.getAudioEncoding());
        AudioRecord recordInstance = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, this.getFrequency(), this
                        .getChannelConfiguration(), this.getAudioEncoding(),
                bufferSize);
        short[] tempBuffer = new short[bufferSize];
        recordInstance.startRecording();
        while (this.isRecording) {
            // Are we paused?
            synchronized (mutex) {
                if (this.isPaused) {
                    try {
                        mutex.wait(250);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Wait() interrupted!",
                                e);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }

            bufferRead = recordInstance.read(tempBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            if (bufferRead == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "read() returned AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION");
            } else if (bufferRead == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "read() returned AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE");
            } else if (bufferRead == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "read() returned AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION");
            }
            try {
                for (int idxBuffer = 0; idxBuffer < bufferRead; ++idxBuffer) {
                    dataOutputStreamInstance.writeShort(tempBuffer[idxBuffer]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "dataOutputStreamInstance.writeShort(curVal)");
            }

        }

        // Close resources...
        recordInstance.stop();
        try {
            bufferedStreamInstance.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot close buffered writer.");
        }
    }

    public void setFileName(File fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public File getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    /**
     * @param isRecording
     *            the isRecording to set
     */
    public void setRecording(boolean isRecording) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            this.isRecording = isRecording;
            if (this.isRecording) {
                mutex.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the isRecording
     */
    public boolean isRecording() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return isRecording;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param frequency
     *            the frequency to set
     */
    public void setFrequency(int frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    /**
     * @return the frequency
     */
    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    /**
     * @param channelConfiguration
     *            the channelConfiguration to set
     */
    public void setChannelConfiguration(int channelConfiguration) {
        this.channelConfiguration = channelConfiguration;
    }

    /**
     * @return the channelConfiguration
     */
    public int getChannelConfiguration() {
        return channelConfiguration;
    }

    /**
     * @return the audioEncoding
     */
    public int getAudioEncoding() {
        return audioEncoding;
    }

    /**
     * @param isPaused
     *            the isPaused to set
     */
    public void setPaused(boolean isPaused) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            this.isPaused = isPaused;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the isPaused
     */
    public boolean isPaused() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return isPaused;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) is your need here. If you do not plan to fiddle around with raw audio data, use a MediaRecorder object to do the recording. Set the output format to THREE_GPP and it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the file extension does not change the file format, so putting .mp3, for example, does not automatically create an MP3 file. AudioRecord produces raw PCM data.

You will have to tell the media player to play a raw file, and what kind of data to expect (sample rate, encoding etc) just as you did when making the recording, since this information is not given by the file itself.

You can read instructions for doing this in Audacity here: http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/playing-raw-pcm-audio-using-audacity/

Answer (score 0):

Think you should use another class then AudioRecord.
AudioRecord is raw digital impressions of what is on your soundport right now.
And what you have "borrowed" up there for an code, is just a series of numbers.

Try AudioManager instead, think thats more your style.